# Spring Integration : QueueChannel guarantee no data loss?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want my system to guarantee there is no data loss even if the system is shutting down.
What this mean is that the system must not miss the request message. So, I will change the way that accept http reqeust. Now, I am using http gateway/webservice gateway in spring integration. But, This isn't receive the message even if the system dies. So, I want to add the queue between the http client and the http receiver. So, I want to use a queue channel. Here is the question.

① I have to install other queue program such as activemq or rabbitmq and have to connect to the queue channel in spring integration?

② and which one is the best combination with spring integration? I heard that rabbit mq is the best one.

please give me a elaborate explanation. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you description isn't clear...

If you don't want to lose messages from the `QueueChannel` use some Persistence `MessageStore`, like `JdbcChannelMessageStore`: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store

From other side there are `channel wrappers` for the AMQP as well as for JMS:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e5846

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jms.html#jms-channel

Which really provide the same persistence durability, fault tollerant options for your use-case.

Re. `activemq` VS `rabbitmq`. I can say by my own expiriance that the last one is better, by configuration, usage from Spring Integration (Spring AMQP is under the shell). And its performance is really better.

All other info you can find in the Internet.